# Querying a High Cardinality Field

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, query-optimization

I am designing a data model for our orders for our upcoming Cassandra migration. An order has an orderId (arcane UUID field) and an orderNumber (user-friendly number). A getOrder query can be done by using any of the two.

My partition key is the orderId, so getByOrderId is not a problem. By getByOrderNumber is - there's a one-to-one mapping b/w the orderId and the orderNumber (high-cardinality field), so creating a local secondary index on each node would slow down my queries.

What I was wondering was that I could create a new table with the orderNumber as the partition key and the orderId as the only column (kind of a secondary index but maintained by me). So now, a getByOrderNumber query can be resolved in two calls.

Bear with me if the above solution is egregiously wrong, I am extremely new to Cassandra. As I understand, for such a column, if I used local secondary indices, Cassandra would have to query each node for a single order. So I thought why not create another table that stores the mapping.

What would I be missing on by managing this index myself? One thing I can see if for every write, I'll now have to update two tables. Anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought why not create another table that stores the mapping.

That's okay. From Cassandra documentation:

> **Do not use an index in these situations**:
>
> On high-cardinality columns because you then query a huge volume of
>   records for a small number of results. See Problems using a
>   high-cardinality column index below.
>
> **Problems using a high-cardinality column index**
>
> If you create an index on a high-cardinality column, which has many
>   distinct values, a query between the fields incurs many seeks for very
>   few results. In the table with a billion songs, looking up songs by
>   writer (a value that is typically unique for each song) instead of by
>   their recording artist is likely to be very inefficient..
>
> It would probably be more efficient to manually maintain the table as
>   a form of an index instead of using the built-in index. For columns
>   containing unique data, it is sometimes fine performance-wise to use
>   an index for convenience, as long as the query volume to the table
>   having an indexed column is moderate and not under constant load.
>
> Conversely, creating an index on an extremely low-cardinality column,
>   such as a boolean column, does not make sense. Each value in the index
>   becomes a single row in the index, resulting in a huge row for all the
>   false values, for example. Indexing a multitude of indexed columns
>   having foo = true and foo = false is not useful.

It's normal for Cassandra data modelling to have a denormalized data.